# Regex: Find/Select all ASCII symbols between words

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++

I want to use regex to find all symbols between `title="` and `Subject`, or to find all lines that contains those symbols between those words:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all:

`(?<=title=")[^\w"]+.*?|^Subject`

Comment: That `|` means the search looks for `(?<=title=")[^\w"]+.*?` or `^Subject` which is not what the qestion wants.

Answer (score 2):

To find special characters after `title="` you can use a lookbehind, and a negative character class.

Find what : `(?<=title=")[^\w"]+`
Search mode : Regular Expressions

To find a whole line:

Find what : `^.*title="[^\w"]+\w+.*$`
Search mode : Regular Expressions (with `. matches new lines` checked off)

Comment: ok, works only for the 4 symbols. But if I have more than 4 ASCII symbols, like 7 symbols, doesn't find/select all of them.

Comment: The `+` matches 1 or more, so 4 or 7 shouldn't matter.  Is it because those special characters are somewhere in that title, not just at the start? Do you have such example where it doesn't find them?

Comment: for the first regex, please look at this printscreen:  https://snag.gy/vxPXHS.jpg

the second regex, doesn't work

Comment: Hmm... it stops at the FF.  Not sure what character that is. Form Feed? What if you remove the `\s` from the regex?  (assuming the FF is considered a whitespace)

Comment: yes, your first regex works without `\s` , but the second regex doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try the new version of the 2nd? Maybe if you remove `Subject` from the regex?

Comment: @JustMe Heh, that FF character is troublesome.  It seems it's also considered an end-of-line, so `.*$` only matches before the FF.  The changed 2nd regex should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a search for `title="([^"\r\n]*?)Subject` and then the wanted characters should be in capture group 1, so they can be accessed as `$1` or `\1` in the replace field.

Note that the capture group excludes string quotes and line ending characters. Also that a non-greedy search is used. These are both done to make the search find the minimal set of characters, ie to avoid confusion with input text such as `title="!%&Subject" xyz="Subject"` or `title="!%&Subject" Subject="xyz"` or `title="!%&Subject 1 and Subject 2"`.

Comment: @JustMe Of course it doesn't. The text in that image has a string quote before `Subject` and that is not shown in your original question.

Comment: The text in the image linked in the comment above is `code bebe text="---"Subject this`. The original question has an image containing `code text="---Subject this`. In both cases the `---` represents a group of characters many of which are outside the set \x20 to \x7F.